# Addings Child to PSObject after Creation

Tags: powershell, psobject

When using Powershell the Add-Member function can be used for manipulation of the object tree.

Following Function should read a CSV with Customers and their corresponding domain names and build a object tree as follows :

```
Customer1--- some attributes
   |__ Domainname1---some attributes
   |__ Domainname2---some attributes
Customer2--- some Attribute 
   |__ Domainname3---some attributes
Customer3--- some attributes
   |__ Domainname1---some attributes
   |__ Domainname2---some attributes
   |__ Domainname3---some attributes
```

The CSV File is a unsorted list of customers with their domains and looks like :

```
Kunde,Domain
"Customer1", "DomainName1"
"Customer2", "DomainName3"
"Customer1", "DomainName2"
"Customer3", "DomainName4"
```

After adding the domainname3 to the customer2 the domainname3 is seen also on the customer1 object  as possible child.

the result tree looks like this in the debugger :

```
Customer1--- some attributes
   |__ Domainname1---some attributes
   |__ Domainname2---some attributes
   |__ Domainname3---some attributes
Customer2--- some Attribute 
   |__ Domainname1---some attributes
   |__ Domainname2---some attributes
   |__ Domainname3---some attributes
```

How can I get the planned result ?

The powershell function :

```
Function ReadCustomerDomains([string]$File )
{
    $CSVData = Import-Csv  $File -Delimiter ","
    $CustomerListObject = New-Object PSObject 
    

    ForEach ($Item in $CSVData)   
    {
        if ( Get-Member -InputObject $CustomerListObject -name $($Item.Kunde) )
        {
        }
        else
        {
            $CustomerListObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "$($Item.Kunde)" -NotePropertyValue $Customer_Properties
        }
    }

    ForEach ($Item in $CSVData)   
    {
        $CustomerItem = $CustomerListObject.$($Item.Kunde)
        Add-Member -InputObject $CustomerItem -NotepropertyName "$($Item.Domain)"  -NotePropertyValue $Customer_Domain_Properties
        $CustomerItem =$Null 
    }
    $CustomerList += $CustomerListObject
    return  $CustomerList
}
```

Comment: Need to see sample of csv.  I like to use class objects when create trees.  Do get tree structure you need to group by customer.  I do not know why you have two foreach loops.

Comment: The second loop was for isolating the problem with the Add-Member Domain Item. Is the child visibility of the domain items normal behavior in the object tree ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
$filename = "c:\temp\test.csv"
$headers = 'Customer', 'Domain'
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $filename -Header $headers
$customers = $csv | Group-Object -Property 'Customer'

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach($customer in $customers)
{
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Customer -NotePropertyValue $customer.Name

   $domainObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
   foreach($domain in $customer.Group)
   {
      $attributes = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,object]]::new()
      for($i = 0; $i -lt 4; $i++)
      {
         $attributes.Add('Attribute' + $i, $i)
      }
      $domainObj | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $domain.Domain -NotePropertyValue $attributes
   }
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Domains -NotePropertyValue $domainObj
   $table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
}
$table | foreach { $_.Customer; $_.Domains | foreach {$_ | Format-List} }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code, this is the solution I was looking for. The only change I had to do :  $Attributes = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,object]]::new() ==> $Attributes = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,object]" , The ::new Constructor was not working on my version of Powershell

Comment: Just verify that you go first row of CSV.  I wasn't sure if your CSV had a header row.  Using -Headers with Import-CSV will treat the header rows as data instead of headers.